# Rails console not loading environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into a bizarre problem. My rails console is not loading parts of my rails environment, but only in production. In development it works fine.

```
:~/production_code/current$ RAILS_ENV=production rbenv exec rails c
        Running via Spring preloader in process 26218
        Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.1)

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata", "markets", "delayed_jobs", "users"]
irb(main):004:0> Market
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
NameError (uninitialized constant Market)
Did you mean?  Marcel
irb(main):005:0>
```

I also does not understand `reset!` and RAILS_ROOT is undefined.

I'm really puzzled as to what's going on and not sure where to investigate from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when spring is running in production. Try either:

```
spring stop
```

or look for running spring process using `ps -eaf | grep spring` and kill them.

Try the console again once spring is stopped successfully.

Comment: Thanks. It's been a while since I've used rails. This is new to me. I'll go read up on it.